# CSS not working in Chrome on specific computers

Tags: css, google-chrome

We are experiencing a strange CSS issue that has us baffled. A co-worker began experiencing the issue first where, only in Chrome, all of the icons on the side menu are "black" instead of the "green" they have been for years.  Here is what they are supposed to look like:

[image]

Here is how they now look in Chrome:

[image]

I was not having the problem until I "Got Latest" of his code from TFVC, and now I am having the same issue.  What is baffling is that we are seeing the issue in Chrome even if we access our production site directly in Chrome (not just when running the project from Visual Studio using localhost), and it is only happening on the 2 of our computers.  When accessing the site using Chrome from other non-development computers the icons still show correctly.  The icons are svg (here is a sample of one):

```
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="24px" height="24px" viewBox="0 0 24 24" version="1.1" class="kt-svg-icon">
                <g stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
                    <polygon id="Shape" points="0 0 24 0 24 24 0 24" />
                    <path d="M12.2928955,6.70710318 C11.9023712,6.31657888 11.9023712,5.68341391 12.2928955,5.29288961 C12.6834198,4.90236532 13.3165848,4.90236532 13.7071091,5.29288961 L19.7071091,11.2928896 C20.085688,11.6714686 20.0989336,12.281055 19.7371564,12.675721 L14.2371564,18.675721 C13.863964,19.08284 13.2313966,19.1103429 12.8242777,18.7371505 C12.4171587,18.3639581 12.3896557,17.7313908 12.7628481,17.3242718 L17.6158645,12.0300721 L12.2928955,6.70710318 Z" id="Path-94" fill="#000000" fill-rule="nonzero" />
                    <path d="M3.70710678,15.7071068 C3.31658249,16.0976311 2.68341751,16.0976311 2.29289322,15.7071068 C1.90236893,15.3165825 1.90236893,14.6834175 2.29289322,14.2928932 L8.29289322,8.29289322 C8.67147216,7.91431428 9.28105859,7.90106866 9.67572463,8.26284586 L15.6757246,13.7628459 C16.0828436,14.1360383 16.1103465,14.7686056 15.7371541,15.1757246 C15.3639617,15.5828436 14.7313944,15.6103465 14.3242754,15.2371541 L9.03007575,10.3841378 L3.70710678,15.7071068 Z" id="Path-94" fill="#000000" fill-rule="nonzero" opacity="0.3" transform="translate(9.000003, 11.999999) rotate(-270.000000) translate(-9.000003, -11.999999) " />
                </g>
            </svg>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
<style>
svg {
    fill: #82CD53 !important;
}
    svg:hover {
        fill: #FFAE3B !important;
    }
.hover-item {
    color: #FFAE3B;
}
```

We have tried clearing cache.  I even tried uninstalling and re-installing Chrome, but the fact the issue is just happening on our 2 computers is really baffling.

Comment: Try using `svg g {fill:` instead of `svg {`

Answer (score 0):

The (fill) property must be applied on the path element. Try this it worked for me!

```
    svg path{
    fill: #82CD53 !important;
}
    svg path:hover {
        fill: #FFAE3B !important;
    }
.hover-item {
    color: #FFAE3B;
}
```

Codepen : https://codepen.io/mouatezbenariba/pen/wvmedGy